# MIT's Programming Language for Cells

Tags: synthetic-biology

I have read a lot about the programming language, Cello, that MIT created to program DNA; however, I cannot seem to find any sources online that shows you how to program with Cello. Are there any good sources out there with regard to this topic?

Thanks

Comment: Since this isn’t necessarily on topic I won’t make this a full answer, but I think this is what you are looking for: https://github.com/CIDARLAB/cello/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 2):

I’m not sure that this is on topic, as you really could have found this information yourself.

1. You don’t quote a source for your info about this, which doesn’t help you or anyone interested in this topic. Here is a [Nature News article](https://www.nature.com/news/biology-software-promises-easier-way-to-program-living-cells-1.19671).
2. If you click on the link in that article you get to the [Cello site](http://www.cellocad.org/). You need to choose a name and password to gain entrance, but are not asked for any personal information. All they will have is the IP number of your computer.

The info on this site will not mean much to anyone not involved in synthetic biology.